# WMIC Query on Creationdate to find old processes

Tags: powershell, wmic

I'm trying to pull information on processes that started more than 1 day ago on my Windows 10 PC. I am having no success matching on the Creationdate field.

`wmic process where "Creationdate < $((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString().toString())" get processid`

ERROR: Description = Invalid query

`wmic process where "Creationdate < 20200906012615" get processid`

ERROR: Description = Invalid query

I do need to use WMIC, if possible.

*UPDATED*

An example of the full query I need:

`` WMIC PROCESS WHERE "commandline LIKE '%_900\`"%' AND commandline LIKE '%data-dir%' AND Creationdate < 20200906012615" CALL TERMINATE ``

Comment: Could you please explain the reason why you need to use [tag:WMIC] for this? `gcim win32_process|?{$_.creationdate -lt (get-date -hour 0 -minute 00 -second 00)}|select -exp processid`.

Comment: Or the Get-Process cmdlet.

Comment: …`gps|?{$_.starttime -lt (get-date -hour 0 -minute 00 -second 00)}|select -exp id`

Comment: WMIC is necessary because I've simplified my situation for SO, the query is complex but only the Creationdate part does not work. I am also querying on the commandline arguments in the process.

Comment: Please provide the full wmi queries, as [tag:WMIC] is simply making a WMI query and formatting the output, there should be no reason why you cannot use `Get-CimInstance` with `Win32_Process` or possibly `Get-Process` to perform the same task(s). I'd even suggest that as WMIC is limited in its filtering criteria, and formatting options, that the other methods would allow for better, faster or more accurate options, and results, _(especially as you'd need to build the `CreationDate` string in the correct format in order to use it in your `WHERE` clause)_.

Comment: @Compo that's good to know, I updated the question. Thank you

Comment: Is the data you're parsing out of commandline not available in Get-Process.Path?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not specifying a process name? and could you please provide the possible command line string(s) you're trying to match with the `LIKE` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in powershell like this, and I think it's the easiest way.  Get-ciminstance actually outputs datetime objects for creationdate, unlike get-wmiobject.  "Process" in wmic is an alias for the win32_process class.

```
get-ciminstance win32_process | 
  where { $_.creationdate -lt (get-date).AddDays(-1) -and 
  $_.commandline -like '*svchost*' } | 
  remove-ciminstance -whatif
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a LIKE filter on the commandline like in my updated question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single line [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) example of my initial comment, expanded to incorporate your provided filtering criteria:

```
$d=get-date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0;gcim win32_process -f "commandline like '%_900`"' and commandline like '%data-dir%' and creationdate<'$d'"|icim -m terminate
```

Comment: Your code executes, however it seems that creationdate does not do what I expected or is not very precise. To test more rapidly I used: ```$d=(get-date).AddSeconds(-30);gcim win32_process -f "commandline like '%_900`"' and commandline like '%data-dir%' and creationdate>'$d'"|icim -m terminate``` and processes much older than 30 secs were killed. Is there a way to use StartTime? I've known that to be accurate in my system.

Answer (score 0):

You must append the '.000000-300' to the CreationDate filter.

In your case:

WMIC PROCESS WHERE "commandline LIKE '%_900`"%' AND commandline LIKE '%data-dir%' AND Creationdate < '20200906012615.000000-300'" ....